# Can't request the weight or style of a font using getFont

Tags: fonts, javafx

Lets say I have a Label in my application that uses some Font (javafx.text.Font). My application does not know that font (not a constant), but it can get the Font object from the label.

Now I want to create a new Font based upon the current Font of that label. So I would write something like this:

```
Font font = label.getFont();
Font modifiedFont = deriveFont(font, FontWeight.BOLD);
```

**The problem is:** I can only get the fonts name/family and size. But I can't request the weight or style. Additionally there is no `deriveFont()` method like with the AWT fonts.

So how am I supposed to create a derived font in JavaFX? Or is this simply not possible (at the moment)?

Comment: In answer to your second question as to how to derive a new font, use one of the static methods on Font, eg: `Font.font( myLabelFont.getFamily(), FontWeight.BOLD, size );`